# OpenLayers - Zooming In / Out By Pinching Fingers On Mobile Devices

Tags: openlayers

I am currently using OpenLayers on a project and noticed that when I pinch in (zoom out) or pinch out (zoom in) with my fingers while over the map, the browser zooms in / out on the page itself rather than the map.

On embedded Google Maps, pinching in / out would zoom out / in on the map itself.  I am assuming this has to do with the fact that Google uses an iFrame while OpenLayers builds a canvas on the current page.

Is there a way to zoom in / out on the map itself with OpenLayers?

Comment: Did you try some of the official OpenLayers examples, like https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/arcgis-tiled.html?  It works as expected in Chrome and Firefox on Android 8.0: only map is zoomed, not the whole page. Please include relevant part of your code in the question.

Comment: @TomazicM I tested the above link and it works as expected with mobile Safari as well.  I am using version 3.X with my project so I am assuming it has to do with that

Comment: Add info that you are using OL 3.x to your question. Maybe somebody has solution for it. As per docs it should work in 3.20.1: https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.html#.defaults. Try examples for this version.

Comment: I tested also OpenLayers 3.20.1  example on mobile Android 8.0 and it works OK. There is something wrong either with your code (maybe older version of OL) or your browsing environment.

Comment: @TomazicM Would there be options that could be set during initialization or with CSS that could affect this behavior?

Comment: Yes, if you change interaction defaults: https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.interaction.html#.defaults

Comment: @TomazicM I didn't see anything in the codebase where `pinchZoom` was explicitly overwritten during initialization.  How would you explicitly set `pinchZoom` to true?  Here's what I've tried so far:  `OL_MAP_OPTIONS.interaction = {pinchZoom: true};  this.map = new ol.Map(OL_MAP_OPTIONS);`

Comment: I cannot test it at the moment, but if I remember correctly, it's map option: `interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({pinchZoom: true})`

Comment: @TomazicM Doesn't change pinch behavior.  Is there anyway to `console.log` the map object to check the `pinchZoom` property after initialization?  I'd like to confirm that it's not JS related

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that much familiar with OpenLayers that I could help you with that.